# Creating UTF-16 newline characters in Python for Windows Notepad

Tags: python, windows, unicode, utf-16, notepad

In Python 2.7 running in Ubuntu this code:

```
f = open("testfile.txt", "w")
f.write("Line one".encode("utf-16"))
f.write(u"\r\n".encode("utf-16"))
f.write("Line two".encode("utf-16"))
```

produces the desired newline between the two lines of text when read in Gedit:

```
Line one﻿
﻿Line two
```

However, the same code executed in Windows 7 and read in Notepad produces unintelligible characters after "Line one" but no newline is recognized by Notepad. How can I write correct newline characters for UTF-16 in Windows to match the output I get in Ubuntu?

I am writing output for a Windows only application that only reads Unicode UTF-16. I've spent hours trying out different tips, but nothing seems to work for Notepad. It's worth mentioning that I can successfully convert a text file to UTF-16 right in the Notepad, but I'd rather have the script save the encoding correctly in the first place.

Comment: As a side note: `"Line one".encode("utf-16")` is kind of a silly thing to do. Normally, you only want to call `encode` on Unicode strings, so you'd do `u"Line one".encode("utf-16")`. (3.x enforces that; 2.7 doesn't.) I'm guessing in this case it's just an artifact of your toy example, not your real code.

Comment: PS, in the future, instead of just saying "unintelligible characters", it's worth actually pasting them here. Seeing line 2 show up as `䰀椀渀攀 琀眀漀` would verify that you've got the off-by-one-byte problem but not the BOM problem, while `＀䳾椀渀攀 琀眀漀` would show that you have both problems, etc.

Comment: Also, it might not be completely unintelligible. Someone who knows Chinese fluently and has a good imagination could probably interpret it as something poetic about Ben climbing into soup bowls from the Han, Ming, and Qing dynasties, and explain how that's a loose figurative translation of "Line two". :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're opening the file in text mode, but trying to use it as a binary file.

This:

```
u"\r\n".encode("utf-16")
```

… encodes to `'\r\0\n\0'`.

Then this:

```
f.write('\r\0\n\0')
```

… converts the Unix newline to a Windows newline, giving `'\r\0\r\n\0'`.

And that, of course, breaks your UTF-16 encoding. Besides the fact that the two `\r\n` bytes will decode into the valid but unassigned codepoint U+0A0D, that's an odd number of bytes, meaning you've got a leftover `\0`. So, instead of `L\0` being the next character, it's `\0L`, aka `䰀`, and so on.

On top of that, you're probably writing a new UTF-16 BOM for each encoded string. Most Windows apps will actually transparently handle that and ignore them, so all you're practically doing is wasting two bytes/line, but it isn't actually correct.

---

The quick fix to the first problem is to open the file in binary mode:

```
f = open("testfile.txt", "wb")
```

This doesn't fix the multiple-BOM problem, but it fixes the broken `\n` problem. If you want to fix the BOM problem, you either use a stateful encode, or you explicitly specify `'utf-16-le'` (or `'utf-16-be'`) for all writes but the first write.

---

But the *easy* fix, for *both* problems, is to use the `io` module (or, for older Python 2.x, the `codecs` module) to do all the hard work for you:

```
f = io.open("testfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
f.write("Line one")
f.write(u"\r\n")
f.write("Line two")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I ended up using the solution with codecs module.

Comment: @I_Ridanovic: Unless you need pre-2.6 support, `io.open` is generally better than `codecs.open`. See [issue 8796](http://bugs.python.org/issue8796) for some of the ways. (Also, if you're using `codecs.open` on Windows and already having newline problems, see [issue 7262](http://bugs.python.org/issue7262) for how the behavior differs from the docs.)