# Cannot write UTF-16LE encoded CSV file with Text::CSV_XS Perl module

Tags: perl, csv, encoding

I want to write a CSV file encoded in UTF-16LE. 
However, the output in the file gets messed up. There are strange chinese looking letters: ਍挀攀氀氀㄀⸀㄀㬀挀攀氀氀㄀⸀㈀㬀ഀ.

This looks like off-by-one-byte problem mentioned here: [Creating UTF-16 newline characters in Python for Windows Notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159236/creating-utf-16-newline-characters-in-python-for-windows-notepad)

Other threads about Perl and Text::CSV_XS didn't help.

This is how I try it:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Text::CSV_XS;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    binary => 1,
    sep_char => ";",
    quote_char => undef,
    eol => $/,
});

open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-16LE)', 'in.csv' or die "in.csv: $!";
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-16LE)', 'out.csv' or die "out.csv: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($in)) {
    $_ =~ s/ä/æ/ for @$row; # something will be done to the data...
    $csv->print($out, $row);
}


close $in;
close $out;
```

in.csv contains some test data and it is encoded in UTF-16LE:

```
header1;header2;
cell1.1;cell1.2;
äöü2.1;ab"c2.2;
```

The results looks like this:

```
header1;header2;਍挀攀氀氀㄀⸀㄀㬀挀攀氀氀㄀⸀㈀㬀ഀ
æöü2.1;abc2.2;਍
```

It is not an option to switch to UTF-8 as output format (which works fine btw).

So, how do I write valid UTF-16LE encoded CSV files using Text::CSV_XS?

Comment: Can you create UTF8 and then use Encode, or Encode::Unicode to transcribe it to UTF-16LE?

Comment: Indeed, this was a workaround I thought about. The file content is not UTF-16, another program simply expects UTF-16. But I don't like it, because it's a workaround. I fear that I'm missing something (trivial?), as I assume that Perl modules - especially those having to do with IO stuff - should be able to handle UTF-16 etc.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question: Would Text::CSV (not XS) be able to handle UTF-16LE?  It doesn't surprise me about the XS module not handling yet another Unicode encoding.

Comment: I tried Text::CSV instead of Text::CSV_XS and verified using $csv->is_pp, but there was no change. The output is still messed up the same way as with the XS module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl adds `:crlf` by default on Windows. It's added first, before your `:encoding` is added.

That means LF⇔CRLF conversion will be performed before decoding on reads, and after encoding on writes. This is backwards.

It ends up working with UTF-8 despite being done backwards because all of the following conditions are met:

- The UTF-8 encoding of LF is the same as its Code Point (0A).
- The UTF-8 encoding of CR is the same as its Code Point (0D).
- 0A always refers to LF no matter where they are in the file.
- 0D always refers to CR no matter where they are in the file.

None of those conditions holds true for UTF-16le.

Fix:

```
open(my $fh_in,  '<:raw:encoding(UTF-16LE):crlf', $qfn_in)
open(my $fh_out, '>:raw:encoding(UTF-16LE):crlf', $qfn_out)
```

Comment: For those just finding this: Use the above but first add a BOM to the filehandle, like so `print $fh chr(0xFEFF)`, before writing with the module's write method. Once I did this, Excel displayed the data properly.

Comment: Yes, if you want to add a BOM, you can do that (or `print $fh "\N{BOM}";`), but that has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: True, the OP doesn't mention Excel, but I find that readability in that program is a common goal of writing UTF16-LE csv files.